Microsoft Message Analyzer cannot start Loopback and Unencrypted IPSEC
I regularly use Microsoft Message Analyzer for tasks at work, and it runs smoothly on my virtual machine. However, when attempting to use it on my local machine, specifically to start Loopback and Unencrypted IPSEC (the latter selected from favorites), I encounter an issue.

The error message displayed is:
"Fail to start live consumer
Unable to start session for Firewall provider.
Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source "

Any guidance or assistance in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Yes, the tools which you mentioned did not found any problems.
